# Why do I get "error: the following arguments are required: wsi_fn"

Tags: python, pycharm, argparse

This is my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  import argparse, pathlib
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('wsi_fn', help='target image filename')
  parser.add_argument('--dst_fn', help='save filename')
  args = parser.parse_args()
```

However, I get the error saying that

```
usage: make_pyramid_tif.py [-h] [--dst_fn DST_FN] wsi_fn
make_pyramid_tif.py: error: the following arguments are required: wsi_fn
```

I'm trying to load an svs file and mask it here. Any idea on how to deal with this error?

Comment: You forgot the "-" before `wsi_fn`.

Comment: `wsi_fn` is a positional argument which means you need to run the script with at least one argument like `make_pyramid_tif.py test.jpg`, the error raised when you just run `make_pyramid_tif.py`

Comment: How did you call this script?  How are you specifying the required file name?  And how about the basics, do you know what a command line argument is?

Comment: OK, I noticed the `pycharm` tag.  Calling a script from that requires more than hitting the `run` button.  You have to specify command line arguments in some extra window or menu.  A lot of new users seem to miss this; I don't know why it's so hard to find in the `pycharm` documentation.